# Laravel session storage jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, session

I have multi paged `form`. And have to save `inputs` to cookie. and if i press `next` or `previous` button. I have to retrieve `session data`How to save each inputs value to session and retrieve them. And how to show back them each input.

**Javascript**

```
$.each($('input[type=number]'),function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

**i think its gonna be like**

```
sessionStorage.setItem('1',input1);
sessionStorage.setItem('2',input2);
sessionStorage.setItem('3',input3);
sessionStorage.setItem('4',input4);
```

Comment: Do you need to save to a cookie, or to sessionStorage? Those are very different things

Comment: which one is better sir in that case. I have no idea which one is good for me.

Comment: Neither is particularly appropriate. Either send the form's data to the server when a page is submitted, and keep it saved until the whole form is submitted, or use `localStorage` to save data over pageloads. Even better, change your design so that the form is on a single page, that way you can keep the information in just a plain variable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is particularly appropriate. Either send the form's data to the server when a page is submitted, and keep it saved until the whole form is submitted, or use localStorage to save data over pageloads.